# Calculate average, sum, count and Seq without org.apache.sql.functions._ in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to perform aggregation such as average, sum, count and Seq for the customer and account data without using the org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ Dataset Api can be used. I have written the code based on functions._

The columns in the customer Data are customerId, forename, surname

The columns in the account data are customerId, accountId, balance

I need to calculate the sum(balance), count(accountId), average(balance) and Seq(AccountData) ie.

{customerId, accountId, balance} as accounts

Below is the code which I have written using functions._

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Assignment1 extends App {
  // Create a Spark session
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Assignment").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  // Set logger level to Warn
  Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF)

  // Create DataFrames for sources
  val customerDF: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", "true")
    .option("sep", "\t").csv("./dataset/customer_data.csv")
  val accountDF = spark.read.option("header", "true")
    .option("sep", "\t").csv("./dataset/account_data.csv")

  // Define case classes
  case class CustomerData(customerId: String, forename: String, surname: String)
  case class AccountData(customerId: String, accountId: String, balance: Long)
  case class CustomerAccountOutput(customerId: String, forename: String, surname: String
                                   ,accounts: Seq[AccountData], numberAccounts: Int, totalBalance: Long, averageBalance: Double)

  // Create DataFrames of case classes
  val customerDS: Dataset[CustomerData] = customerDF.as[CustomerData]

  val accountDS: Dataset[AccountData] = accountDF.withColumn("balance", 'balance.cast("long")).as[AccountData]

  val customerAccountDS: Dataset[CustomerAccountOutput] = customerDS
    .join(accountDS, Seq("customerId"), "left_outer")
    .groupBy(customerDS.col("customerId"), customerDS.col("forename"), customerDS.col("surname"))
    .agg(
      coalesce(collect_set(struct(accountDS.col("customerId"), accountDS.col("accountId"),
        accountDS.col("balance"))), array()).alias("accounts"),
      count(accountDS.col("accountId")).cast("Int").alias("numberAccounts"),
      sum(accountDS.col("balance")).alias("totalBalance")
    ).withColumn("averageBalance", col("totalBalance") / col("numberAccounts"))
    .na.fill(0).as[CustomerAccountOutput]

  customerAccountDS.printSchema()

  customerAccountDS.show(truncate = false)
}
```

Comment: Is this an exercise? Why would you want not to use these functions?

Comment: Yes, this is an exercise where I shouldn't use it

Comment: Then, what did you try? SO is a place to help with specific issues. Not to do your homeworks.

Comment: I have given the code which I have tried using functions, I'm not able to proceed without that, Here is the snippet which I have tried,

Comment: val accountStatsDs: Dataset[AccountStats] = accountDS
    .groupBy($"customerId")
    .agg(Map("accountId" -> "count", "balance" -> "sum", "newBalance" -> "avg"))
    .withColumnRenamed("customerId", "customerId")
    .withColumnRenamed("count(accountId)", "numberAccounts")
    .withColumnRenamed("sum(balance)", "totalBalance")
    .withColumnRenamed("avg(newBalance)", "averageBalance")
    .selectExpr("cast(customerId as String)", "cast(numberAccounts as Int)", "cast(totalBalance as Long)",
      "cast(averageBalance as Double)")
    .as[AccountStats]

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I agree on the homework point look at selectExpr docs and various examples via google.  Hint - do not use withColumn/Renamed if you also want performance.

Comment: Thanks Chris, will definitely try it out